# Input button target="_blank" isn't causing the link to load in a new window/tab

Tags: html, button, input, target

I have an HTML file with an input button. 
This is only an example button, but it's including all necessary info of code:

```
<input type="button" onClick="parent.location='http://www.facebook.com/'" value="facebook" target="_blank">
```

For some reason, it's not loading in a new window/tab.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you will need to do it like this...

```
<a type="button" href="http://www.facebook.com/" value="facebook" target="_blank" class="button"></a>
```

and add the basic css if you want it to look like a btn.. like this

```
    .button {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 0 #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 0 #fff;
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 0 0 #fff;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffffff), color-stop(1, #d1d1d1) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffffff 5%, #d1d1d1 100% );
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#d1d1d1');
    background-color:#fff;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#777;
    font-family:Helvetica;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:700;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #fff
}



  .button:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #d1d1d1), color-stop(1, #ffffff) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #d1d1d1 5%, #ffffff 100% );
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#d1d1d1', endColorstr='#ffffff');
    background-color:#d1d1d1
}
.button:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px
}
```

target works only with href tags..

Comment: I've tried this, but it won't make it look like button?! http://jsfiddle.net/6v4q2/

Comment: here is sample and it does works. you have to add the effect to make push effect, i can provided just in 10 min two ;)

Comment: Aah, that dot in front of the button value in css. Now it's working :)

Comment: i edit it so also looks more like a btn while hover and press

Comment: @jycr753 formtarget="_blank"

Comment: @mans Where do you have the reference for that att? I cant it and as I far i cant remember i have never seen something call "formtarget"

Comment: That's a HTML5 tag. Not supported in all major browsers.

Comment: @user952851 that is basic html, if you are talking about CSS3, that is another thing, but again it is supported by all major browsers, and for those that have IE8 there is a small fallback `filter:progid:` so they can have some small experience.. if they want the real experience they should get a real browser

Answer (score 54):

use `formtarget="_blank"` its working for me

```
<input type="button" onClick="parent.location='http://www.facebook.com/'" value="facebook" formtarget="_blank">
```

**Browser compatibility**: from [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=formtarget)
**IE**: 10+
| **Edge**: 12+
| **Firefox**: 4+
| **Chrome**: 15+
| **Safari/iOS**: 5.1+
| **Android**: 4+

Comment: Make sure you tell people this HTML5 tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formtarget.asp

Comment: Unfortunately the provided link states that _The formtarget attribute is only used for buttons with type="submit"_. It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 18):

Just use the javascript [window.open](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) function with the second parameter at "_blank"

```
<button onClick="javascript:window.open('http://www.facebook.com', '_blank');">facebook</button>
```

Comment: This should actually have been accepted as the right answer

Answer (score 17):

The correct answer:

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="" target="_blank"></form>
```

Supported in all major browsers :)

Comment: Tested it in IE7+, Chrome, FF, and Safari

Comment: Sometimes somebody wants some buttons (hyperlinks) to open in a new window, but not others. This is all-or-nothing for all hyperlink-buttons, correct?

Answer (score 6):

Facing a similar problem, I solved it this way:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_top" style="text-decoration:none"><button id="back">Back</button></a>
```

Change *_top* with *_blank* if this is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for that, i had the same problem with wicket that it couldnt get the right class (like a button) for the href , and this answer solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

Please try this
it's working for me

onClick="**window.open**('http://www.facebook.com/','facebook')"

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-social" onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/','facebook')">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

An `input` element does not support the `target` attribute. The `target` attribute is for `a` tags and that is where it should be used.

Answer (score 3):

`target` isn't valid on an `input` element.

In this case, though, your redirection is done by Javascript, so you could have your script open up a new window.

Answer (score 3):

> The formtarget attribute is only used for buttons with type="submit".

That is from this [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formtarget.asp).

Here is an answer using *JavaScript*:

```
<input type="button" onClick="openNewTab()" value="facebook">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function openNewTab() {
        window.open("http://www.facebook.com/");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form target="_blank">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" formaction="http://www.google.com">Google</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

> onClick="parent.location='http://www.facebook.com/'"

try using

> onClick="**window.open**='http://www.facebook.com/'"
>   onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/','facebook')"

Answer (score 0):

In a similar use case, this worked for me...

```
<button onclick="window.open('https://www.w3.org/', '_blank');">  My Button </button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another solution,  using JQUERY,  would be to write a function that is invoked when the user clicks the button. This function creates a new `<A>` element, with target='blank', appends this to the document, 'clicks' it then removes it.

So as far as the user is concerned, they clicked a button, but behind the scenes, an `<A>` element with target='_blank' was clicked.

```
<input type="button" id='myButton' value="facebook">

$(document).on('ready', function(){
     $('#myButton').on('click',function(){
         var link = document.createElement("a");
         link.href = 'http://www.facebook.com/';
         link.style = "visibility:hidden";
         link.target = "_blank";
         document.body.appendChild(link);
         link.click();
         document.body.removeChild(link); 
     });
});
```

JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ragDaniel/tf991u4g/2/

Answer (score -2):

You Can Put it inside an anchor tag

```
     <button>
        <a href="{{route('main.home')}}" class="btn header-item noti-icon waves-effect" target="_blank"><i class="bx bxs-home"></i></a>
     </button>
```

Comment: No, you can't. HTML doesn't allow links inside buttons (or vice versa). Depending on browser error recovery is not recommended.

Comment: A better approach is to replace the button with a link … like the accepted answer from a decade ago says to do.

Comment: idk about you but its working for me , and ive been using this method for awhile now , it works fine , you can also use onclick function inside your link aswell , but this method is much simpler

Comment: "idk about you but its working for me" — I repeat: Depending on browser error recovery is not recommended.

Comment: "you can also use onclick function inside your link aswell" — The suggestion on the accepted answer, that is referenced, is to use a link **without** `onclick`