# opening Url.Action in new tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a button which opens a URL action, which contains a .PDF file. I need this button to open the PDF file in a new tab when clicked. Although currently it opens in the same tab.

Current code:

```
<button target="_blank" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("OpenPDF", "FlaggedSurveys", new { id = ViewBag.CompletedCamp } )'" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true" target="_blank"></span> Open Survey PDF
        </button>
```

I have also tried fromtarget"_blank":

```
<button formtarget="_blank" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("OpenPDF", "FlaggedSurveys", new { id = ViewBag.CompletedCamp } )'" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Open Survey PDF
        </button>
```

Can someone tell me how to get the first Button opening on a new tab please?

Comment: did you check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207342/input-button-target-blank-isnt-causing-the-link-to-load-in-a-new-window-tab

Comment: as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button .. the attribute is called formtarget  not target for buttons

Comment: I have tried fromtarget, and it still opens in the same tab. "<button formtarget="_blank" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("OpenPDF", "FlaggedSurveys", new { id = ViewBag.CompletedCamp } )'" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Open Survey PDF
        </button>"

Comment: window.open instead of location.href will sort your issue : <button formtarget='_blank' onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/')" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
open
</button>

Comment: if this satisfies your business i will submit it as an answer

Comment: @HanyHabib I need to open an action method, I am not too sure how this will work? I tried the following and nothings happens when I click the button: <button formtarget="_blank" onclick="window.open='@Url.Action("OpenPDF", "FlaggedSurveys", new { id = ViewBag.CompletedCamp } )'" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Open Survey PDF
        </button>

Comment: can u post here the rendered button.. so i can see the full output

Comment: <button formtarget="_blank" onclick="window.open='/FlaggedSurveys/OpenPDF/4'" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Open Survey PDF
        </button>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210505/discussion-between-hany-habib-and-craig2020).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For it to work you can try :

```
<button formtarget="_blank" onclick="window.open('@Url.Action("OpenPDF", "FlaggedSurveys", new { id = ViewBag.CompletedCamp } )')" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Open Survey PDF </button>
```

a working example:

```
<button formtarget="_blank" onclick="window.open('www.google.com')" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Open Survey PDF </button>
```